# ¿Error de SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2017

la semana pasada hice un post en relación a algo similar. Seré breve... Por que en en 4 de 6 computadoras puedo agregar registros sin problema a la Base de datos en SQL Server y en las otras dos maquinas me genera error que las tablas, como por ejemplo que no tienen la misma definición o que no se puede convertir equis cosa o identity is on.

Siento que no es error de codigo ya que si no, en ninguna de las 6 computadoras pudiera agregar registros, Debo decir que no hace mucho modifique 2 tablas... siento que por alli va el caso pero no se que hacer.

Uso SQL Server Management Studio 2018

[image: aqui son los errores que geera en las dos computadoras.]

[image: Aquí otro error, que como digo en las otras 4 computadoras no me genera ninguno d elos dos errores... solo en las 2 que ya mencione]

de allí en fuera puedo hacer consultar en las 6 computadoras sin problema.

Por favor, ayuda.

Comment: los errores son claramente del codigo en relacion a la db.. estas seguro que en esas donde falla, la db esta en la version que vos queres?

Comment: Están probando con los mismos valores en las 6? Seguro que están usando la misma BD? Hubo algún cambio en la BD?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2018 <--- es una ide para conectarte a una base de datos.. no es ni una base de datos ni nada que nos ayude a ayudarte ;)

Comment: @Alfabravo fijate que modifico 2 tablas.. lo dice en el post... no hizo bien los upgrades...

Comment: @gbianchi exacto bro... no hice bien los upgrades... de hecho no lo hice, lo que hice fue eliminar la tabla y agregar "la misma tabla" pero cambiada, ya que practicamente no tenia registros

Comment: y entonces? la pregunta cual es?

Comment: @gbianchi Estoy provando agregando exactamente lo mismo en las 6 computadoras de las cuales en 2 falla bro.

Comment: hace bien los upgrades...

Comment: @gbianchi ando perdido con el hecho de por que solo en esas dos no puedo agregar registros...

Comment: @gbianchi meaconsejarias entonces, dejar la tabla desde antes de los cambios y luego emterle los cambios actualizando la tabla en vez de eliminarla y crear esa misma con diferentes columnas?

Comment: Si tienes manera de ejecutar consultas (sql managment studio), pregúntale a las vistas del sistema, como son tus tablas select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = N'aquí el nombre de la tabla' . Luego compara con tú código, y ya sabrás donde está la/las columnas que están generando ese error. Una vez las tengas localizadas, puedes aplicar un alter table nameTable alter column nameColumn tipoDato

Comment: hsy una sola db o varias?

Comment: Gracias, empezare a probar sus soluciones. vendré a informar avances o resolución del problema. Muchísimas gracias.